# Spring: Error 400 with @RequestBody and JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following parts of code. When I send the HTTP request, I get an error 400 related to carCoordinates field (if I remove it, everything is fine). It is supposed to be a list of double.

Also, when I change the name carCoordinates to carcoordinates without changing getter name, the request is well received but I can't get the data since getter is not linked with the object (null). If I change the getter name to getCarcoordinates to match the field, it doesn't work anymore.
Any ideas why it does not work?

CarEvent.java :

```
Public class CarEvent {
    @JsonProperty("carCoordinates")
    protected List carCoordinates;
    ...
    public void setCarCoordinates(Coordinate c) {
        ...
    }
   
    public List getCarCoordinates() {
        return CarCoordinates;
    }
}
```

The JSON sent is :

```
{
  "id": [006001556, 631016236, 125899724],
  "speed": "0",
  "carCoordinates": [56.477369, 26.64477, 56.466177, 26.651258, 80.545048, 50.614582],
  "num": "5"
}
```

The server class that is requested is:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/car-action", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public String CarAction(@RequestBody CarEvent requestBody, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem probably is your setter method. Your field is of type `List` but the setter takes in an Object of `Coordinate`. Based on your json request I think it should be:

```
public void setCarCoordinates(List c) {
   this.carCoordinates = c;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, it works now !
I didn't know setter method signature was important for the mapping.
Thank you so much !

Comment: Great. Yeah its important, jackson internally uses the setter methods with reflection to set the fields.

Answer (score 2):

Your `CarEvent` 
has setter method with wrong argument.
either create a class `Coordinate` and extend to List or
Update as below:

```
public void setCarCoordinates(List cordinates) {
    ...
}
```